# Get time that program ran (Python)

Tags: python, string, time, python-imaging-library

Im writing a Python script and im going to make it say last updated: and then the time it lst updated but im not sure how

here is and example code

```
from PIL import ImageDraw
import ctypes, time
import urllib
import manipulate
import datetime



font_size = 50
font_color = "red"

font = ImageFont.load_default() 
img = Image.open('bg.bmp')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

time = datetime.datetime.now()


draw.text((650, 450),'                      CURRENT GRADES' )
draw.text((650, 500), 'Period 1: Geography -----------------------------')
draw.text((650, 550), 'Period 2: Francais-------------------------------')
draw.text((650, 600), 'Period 3: Science--------------------------------')
draw.text((650, 650), 'Period 4: P.E------------------------------------')
draw.text((650, 700), 'Period 5: Algebra 9------------------------------')
draw.text((650, 750), 'Period 6: LA-------------------------------------')
draw.text((650, 800), 'Last Updated:'(time))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img.save('mod_bg.bmp')







pathToBmp = "C:\Python27\mod_bg.bmp"
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20  
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, pathToBmp ,
                                       0)
```

and where the Last Updated is i need the time to come after

when i try it i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Project.py", line 28, in <module>
draw.text((650, 800), 'Last Updated:'(time))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

if anyone can help please do!
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
draw.text((650, 800), 'Last Updated: {0}'.format(now))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `'Last Updated:'(time)` part. You are putting parentheses after the string, and thus treating it as a function. You should do `'Last Updated: %s' % time`.